# Traceback error and "argument of type 'int' is not iterable" when trying to use while loop

Tags: python, int, collatz

Im trying to write my first program ever, a collatz sequense program. The code is

```
input_siffra = input("Input an integer: ")
startsiffra = int(input_siffra)

def Collatz(collatz_number):
    position = (len(str(collatz_number)) - 1)
    if position in collatz_number in (0, 2, 4, 6, 8):
        return (collatz_number / 2)
    else:
        return (collatz_number * 3 + 1)

while startsiffra != 1:
    print(startsiffra)
    Collatz(startsiffra)
```

What im trying to do here is find a way to tell if the number i put in is even or odd (yes i know there is the % 2 method but im deliberately trying to not use it here to learn) by looking at the last digit in said number, and then do one of two things if its even or odd. Running this gives me two errors, first a traceback for Collatz(startsiffra) and the int error for the line checking if the last number is in a list.

Comment: What is this line supposed to mean: `if position in collatz_number in (0, 2, 4, 6, 8):`?

Comment: Its supposed to check if the last digit in the number is even

Comment: `position in collatz_number in (0, 2, 4, 6, 8)` is actually shorthand for `(position in collatz_number) and (collatz_number in (0, 2, 4, 6, 8))`. The last digit of a decimal number is its remainder after division by 10, a.k.a. `number % 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
input_siffra = input("Input an integer: ")
startsiffra = int(input_siffra)

def Collatz(collatz_number):
    position = (len(str(collatz_number)) - 1)
    if collatz_number%10 in (0, 2, 4, 6, 8):
        return (collatz_number / 2)
    else:
        return (collatz_number * 3 + 1)

while startsiffra != 1:
    print(startsiffra)
    startsiffra=Collatz(startsiffra)
```

This seems to work as you wished. Hope I helped

EDIT: You can also use this if instead of the one i put in the code. Its what you had been trying to do in you code (without using %)

```
if str(collatz_number)[position] in ('0', '2', '4', '6', '8'):
```

Comment: This worked but if i use the code you added as an edit (to not use %) the program goes on for eternity instead